# Copying a value down into inserted blank rows over multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with multiple columns and in column A there is data where I have removed the duplicates.

This is the code to insert nine blank lines below each of the unique values.

```
Sub RowAdder()
    Dim i As Long, col As Long, lastRow As Long
    col = 1 lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(i - 1, col) <> Cells(i, col) Then
            Range(Cells(i, col).EntireRow, Cells(i + 8, col).EntireRow).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

I need to adapt this code to copy the values of each unique value to the blank lines below for column A to C.

On the last line I need the value to be copied down into 9 blank rows.

Comment: add a screenshot of a before and after scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you'ar after something like this

```
Sub RowAdder()    
    Dim i As Long, col As Long

    col = 1        
    With Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
        For i = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row To 3 Step -1
            If Cells(i - 1, col) <> Cells(i, col) Then Range(Cells(i, col).EntireRow, Cells(i + 8, col).EntireRow).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Next i
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count + 9)
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
                Intersect(.EntireRow, Range("B:C")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            End With
            With Intersect(.EntireRow, Range("A:C"))
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End With
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: This was helpful thank you but I have encountered an unexpected error.  When using this code the value in column A is copied into all the blank cells including column B and C (My apologies for misstating it in my question) What I need is the value in Column B to be copied into the empty cells in Column B and the value of Column C to be copied into the empty cells in column C keeping the formats of the columns.

Comment: Is it possible to also include in the code above code to copy a fixed range of cells (10 Rows of a single column) on another sheet into one of the empty columns (column D) until the last row of data in column A is reached?